# Replacing values of same bins or category from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
[56.7,7068.7], [57.19,7040.4], [60.71,8974.25], [60.875,8933.8],
[60.93,8891.3], [60.955,9479.7], [60.965,8962.35], [61.01,9044.8],
[61.01,8980.35], [61.145,9438.5], [61.28,9441.15], [61.375,9042.5],
[61.45,9374.5], [61.46,9431.6], [61.47,9533.5], [61.5,9427.8]
], columns=['RPM','Power'])


def round_to_value(number,roundto):
    return (round(number / roundto) * roundto)

rpmstart=round_to_value(df['RPM'].min(),0.5)
rpmend=round_to_value(df['RPM'].max(),0.5)+1
groups=df.groupby(pd.cut(df['RPM'], np.arange(rpmstart,rpmend,1.0))).mean()
groups['band']=groups.index
df['avg']=pd.cut(df['RPM'], np.arange(rpmstart,rpmend,1.0))
```

The original question is here: [Averaging a quantity for a particular RPM band and replacing in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939573/averaging-a-quantity-for-a-particular-rpm-band-and-replacing-in-pandas-dataframe)

Basically, I want to be able to average the power for a 1 rpm band, starting from 56.5-57.5 in the ablev dataframe and replace the power value for the relevant RPM bands in the dataframe 'df'. 
I did this code which does it partially and I am stuck. Dataframe 'groups' has the RPM range and the mean power and 'df.avg' has the RPM bands too. How can I replace the power from 'groups' into 'df' for the same band?Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. This is the final code which will find which interval the RPM lies and find the average power for all the powers in that interval.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
[56.7,7068.7], [57.19,7040.4], [60.71,8974.25], [60.875,8933.8],
[58.5,8250.3], [58.6,8520.7], [58.8,8999.0], [59.2,9020.1],
[60.93,8891.3], [60.955,9479.7], [60.965,8962.35], [61.01,9044.8],
[61.01,8980.35], [61.145,9438.5], [61.28,9441.15], [61.375,9042.5],
[61.45,9374.5], [61.46,9431.6], [61.47,9533.5], [61.5,9427.8],[59.6,8920]
], columns=['RPM','Power'])

def round_to_value(number,roundto):
    return (round(number / roundto) * roundto)

rpmstart=round_to_value(df['RPM'].min(),0.5)
rpmend=round_to_value(df['RPM'].max(),0.5)+1
groups=df.groupby(pd.cut(df['RPM'], np.arange(rpmstart,rpmend,1.0))).mean()
groups['band']=groups.index
glen=range(0,len(groups))
groups['in']=glen
groups=groups.set_index('in')
df['band']=pd.cut(df['RPM'], np.arange(rpmstart,rpmend,1.0))
df3=pd.merge(df,groups, on=['band'], how='inner')                       
df3=df3.rename (columns={'Power_x':'Avg_Shaft_Power', 
'Power_y':'RPM_Avg_Power', 'RPM_x':'Avg_Shaft_Speed'})
df3.drop(['RPM_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Thank You.

Regards
Arun